# Which Eclipse download for developing for Java ME

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, ide

I am new in Java ME. I need to download J2ME with Eclipse and follow the guide from [the j4me Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/j4me/wiki/Setup). The problem is when I jump to the official Eclipse site, I see approximately 12 options. Which one do I need?

Comment: Eclipse is spelled with 2 'e's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [Eclipse pulsar.](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/) Its mobile platform version of eclipse. Then download the [sun java toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) or [Java ME SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html) and install it. After that you need to integrate with that SDK with Eclipse. Just follow the following step.

```
window -> preferences -> Java ME -> Device Management -> Manual Install -> select SDK workspace -> finish.
```

**Edit:** J4ME is development framework for Java ME. If you looking for 3rd party development framework for Java ME, I suggest to use [LWUIT.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit/6165904#6165904)

Comment: thats great elaboration. can you give me more information? +1

Comment: what is differance btwn `Eclipse pulsar`.`Eclipse IDE for Java Developers` ? for good start.?

Comment: Eclipse pulsar is mobile platform IDE. If you are using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers means you need to add [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) plugin for developing mobile application. Better you can use Eclipse pulsar. :)

Comment: is there any devlopment differance btwn them?

Comment: one more thing is that  :: `ProGuard` and `J2MEUnit` and `Antenna` are also need to integrate for good start of j2me?

Comment: Yeah you can integrate with Eclipse pulsar. There is no development difference between them. Eclipse pulsar having mobile platform for java developers. General eclipse it doesn't have.

Comment: [Download latest version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) of LWUIT and extract it. Add the `LWUIT_MIDP.jar` into your project properties from that extracted package(see on lib folder). Then you can start your development using LWUIT. :)

Comment: I can't understand. Do you need how to implement?

Answer (score 4):

To quote from the page you linked to:

> The base installation package for Java development is all you need.

So the one labeled "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" should be fine.

Comment: is j2me is different from j4me?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but from your questions and comments here it seems like you don't read the information you find closely enough. j4me is a library that helps with developing J2ME applications. J2ME (or these days: Java ME) is the Java Mobile Edition for developing software running on cell phones and other mobile devices.