# Using LWUIT in eclipse for j2me development

Tags: eclipse, java-me, lwuit

I am new to the LWUIT and I need to know what are the steps to install and use LWUIT in eclipse.

Is there any specific eclipse version required or it can be run over any eclipse?

Comment: You should search before asking a question because It could be answered. Take a look on that, It will be helpfull.
<p>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821261/which-eclipse-download-for-developing-for-java-me

Comment: Thanks .. i need the link for lwuit and i have eclipse Galileo .. . will it work

Comment: i have added the LWUIT jar file in external jars and it does'nt import by it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps to creating new LWUIT application.

- Download [Eclipse pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/)(I preferred) and [LWUIT 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html).
- Download and install the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html)  or [JAVA ME
  SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html).
- Open  the Eclipse and go to ***windows-> preference -> Java ME -> Device
  Management -> manually install*** and then add the that toolkit emulator on the Eclipse.
- Extract the LWUIT 1.5.
- Create the new Java ME project in Eclipse and Add the LWUIT_MIDP.jar(look on the
  lwuit 1.5/lib folder) on created project properties.
- Go through the [reference article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/) and start your work.

Comment: its does not have midp_ui.jar file

Comment: i have downloaded LWUIT_1_5  ... but the path does not have midp_ui.jar file

Comment: I changed the jar file name. check it.

Comment: Now i have created a new  Midlet Suite ... Added a new Midlet and have run the whole program .. the emulator shows up and disappears gives error asNo audio device found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Demo
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+29)
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(+52)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(+28)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(+80)

Comment: Can you tell me the flow for how to you created? And also look [this article for how to develop lwuit application with eclipse.](http://jimmod.com/blog/2010/04/basic-lwuit-tutorial-with-eclipse-pulsar/)

Comment: After opening the Eclipe galileo > New project > new MidletSuite > MidletSuite got created > then i imported the External LWUIT_MIDP.jar > then create a new new MIDLET > then i wrote the whole program with no complilation error , but when i run the program it shows  java.lang.CLASSNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION

Comment: Have you add the Java ME sdk (Sun Java Toolkit or Java ME SDK3.0)?

Comment: @yatinkharbe If you have a different question about another topic, then *ask another question*, do *not* ask another question in the comments.